# How to solve: ImportError: "No module named 'graphlab'?

Tags: python, anaconda, graphlab

With 
    "source activate graphlab" 
in the terminal I can start up graphlab.

I've created it like this: "conda create -n graphlab python=2.7 anaconda", because using virtualenv with Anaconda is untested and not recommended (according to the warning in the terminal, I don't know whether this really is the case.).

After starting up graphlab the terminal shows:

```
discarding /Users/username/anaconda/bin from PATH
prepending /Users/username/anaconda/envs/graphlab/bin to PATH
```

But when I want to import graphlab in the Spider IDE it shows the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/username/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 580, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)
File "/Users/username/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 48, in execfile
exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
File "/Users/username/Documents/projectname/pythonfile.py", line 3, in <module>
import graphlab as gl
ImportError: No module named 'graphlab'
```

How can I solve this? I am totally new to installing these things, so hopefully someone can help me with an extensive step by step explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The Dato Graphlab Create installer did not actually install graphlab on my Mac (El Capitan).  I did the following (Anaconda is installed) in a terminal window:

```
% pip install graphlab-create
```

That subsequently installed Graphlab Create.  You can then easily verify:

```
% python
Python 2.7.10 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Sep 15 2015, 14:29:08)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import graphlab
>>>
```

I've noticed that occasionally, Python will forget that Graphlab Create is installed.  A repeat of the above 'pip' command will cause it to remember.

[python](/questions/tagged/python) [anaconda](/questions/tagged/anaconda) [graphlab](/questions/tagged/graphlab)

Comment: python never forgets

Answer (score 2):

Open Anaconda command prompt. Run the following command:

```
pip install graphlab-create
```

Answer (score 1):

The Spider IDE seems to be configured to use Python3.4 by default. That has to be changed to 2.7. This is from the error message on the issue.

Comment: I've fixed that problem now, but now I still get the following error message:

  File "/Users/username/Documents/python/projectname/pythonfile.py", line 3, in <module>
    import graphlab as gl

ImportError: No module named graphlab

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue with the Spider IDE.

Try importing from the command line interpreter (Anaconda version) and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error message, although I for sure had installed GraphLab on an environment with conda on Windows. I solved it with kernels for different environments.
Do the following on command line:

> activate myenv
>
> python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv --display-name "Python (myenv)"

- replace myenv in the code above with the name of the (conda-)environment in which graphlab is installed

Source (kernels for different environments): https://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html

Oh and to be sure that you actually had installed graphlab correct in your environment in the first place, you can test this by doing in command line:

Change environment:

> activate nameofyourenvironment

Start Python:

> python

Check in Python if GraphLab is found:

> import graphlab

(if you don't get an error message, you did install graphlab correct in that particular environment)